# speed up python scrapy crawler

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently writing vacancies scraper with Scrapy to parse about 3M of vacancies item.
Now I'm on place when spider works and successfully scraping items and storing it tot postgreesql but the thing is it doing it pretty slow.
For 1 hr i stored only 12k vacancies so i'm really ti far from 3M of them.
Thing is that in the end i'm gonna need to scrape and update data once per day and with current performance I'm gonna need more than a day to just parse all data.

I'm new in data scraping so I may do some basic thing wrong and I'll be very gratefull if anybody can hel me.

Code of my spider:

```
import scrapy
import urllib.request
from lxml import html
from ..items import JobItem


class AdzunaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "adzuna"

    start_urls = [
            'https://www.adzuna.ru/search?loc=136073&pp=10'
        ]

    def parse(self, response):

        job_items = JobItem()

        items = response.xpath("//div[@class='sr']/div[@class='a']")

        def get_redirect(url):
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            response_code = response.read()
            result = str(response_code, 'utf-8')
            root = html.fromstring(result)
            final_url = root.xpath('//p/a/@href')[0]
            final_final_url = final_url.split('?utm', 1)[0]
            return final_final_url

        for item in items:
            id = None
            data_aid = item.xpath(".//@data-aid").get()
            redirect = item.xpath(".//h2/a/@href").get()
            url = get_redirect(redirect)
            url_header = item.xpath(".//h2/a/strong/text()").get()
            if item.xpath(".//p[@class='as']/@data-company-name").get() == None:
                company = item.xpath(".//p[@class='as']/text()").get()
            else:
                company = item.xpath(".//p[@class='as']/@data-company-name").get()
            loc = item.xpath(".//p/span[@class='loc']/text()").get()
            text = item.xpath(".//p[@class='at']/span[@class='at_tr']/text()").get()
            salary = item.xpath(".//p[@class='at']/span[@class='at_sl']/text()").get()

            job_items['id'] = id
            job_items['data_aid'] = data_aid
            job_items['url'] = url
            job_items['url_header'] = url_header
            job_items['company'] = company
            job_items['loc'] = loc
            job_items['text'] = text
            job_items['salary'] = salary

            yield job_items

        next_page = response.css("table.pg td:last-child ::attr('href')").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

Comment: can you share your settings.py

Comment: What about your database performance? Do you have correct indexes?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use indexes in your table
2. Insert in BULK instead of inserting one-by-one
3. Minimize use of `meta` in your `Request`
4. Use tuple instead of list where possible
5. Set `CONCURRENT_ITEMS=100`, setting it to higher decreases performance
6. Try to use less Middlewares and Pipielines
7. Set `AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED=False` in settings.py
8. Set `TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED=False` in settings.py